# Trying To Develop a Scoring System for Blackjack Game

Tags: python

so I'm trying to make a scoring system using my current code for blackjack. The game is versus the computer and a player and the rules are a bit different , but that has all been setup. I need to purpose the code for scoring both player and computer's cards. I also should make it so an ace is set to be the value of 1, if to avoid busting. I was thinking of doing so as cards are drawn, but I'm not entirely sure. I tried cross class variables and I didn't find much success. Maybe I could fuse the player and deck classes?

Anyways, here is what I have, I'll provide any more information you need and there should be fairly thorough comments.

```py
# This is a game of blackjack versus a computer.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# importing necessary files
import random

# A couple global variables for any necessary repeats and scoring.
RepeatCardChoice = 0
YourScore = 0
ComputerScore = 0
HitCount = 0  # The amount of times the player hits. Used for showing cards.

# Our deck itself.
class Card:  # This is for developing the cards in the first place.
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def show(self):
        print(str(self.rank) + str(self.suit))

class Deck:  # This is for deck behaviors and creating a deck.
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.Cards()

    def Cards(self):
        for suit in ["S", "C", "D", "H"]:  # S = Spades, C = Clubs, D = Diamonds, and H = Hearts
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                value = rank
                if rank == 1:
                    rank = 'A'  # Makes all 1 values = to ace.
                elif rank == 11:
                    rank = 'J'  # Makes all 11 values = to jack or j.
                elif rank == 12:
                    rank = 'Q'  # Makes all 12 values = to queen or Q.
                elif rank == 13:
                    rank = 'K'  # Makes all 13 values = to king or K.
                if rank == (11) or (12) or (13):
                    value = 10
                elif rank == 1:
                    value == 11
                self.value = value
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def show(self):  # Shows each card individually.
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()  # Really just reusing another function to display results.

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

class Player:  # This class is for player behaviors such as drawing and showing your hand.
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Allows the player to choose their name.
        self.hand = []  # Assigns their cards to a list, to be saved.
        self.Deck = Deck()

    def draw(self, deck, CardCount):  # How the player draws one card at a time. It wasn't necessary to allow more.
        count = 0
        while count != CardCount:
            count += 1
            self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self

    def showHand(self, showCount):  # Shows each card in the player's hand.
        count = 0  # A counter is used to limit how much is drawn.
        for card in self.hand:  # This is so "card" doesn't stay an unresolved reference.
            if count == showCount:
                return
            count += 1
            card.show()

# Below is where we apply the classes and play the game. The computer will operate without input, unlike the player.
# Here is the deck.
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()  # Shuffling the deck in preparation.

PlayerName = str(input('What is your name?'))  # Just so the player can choose their name.

# Setting up the players.
Computer = Player("The Computer")
You = Player(PlayerName)

# Giving both players their hand to start off with.
Computer.draw(deck, 2)
You.draw(deck, 2)

# Here is where one card in each hand is shown.
print('You are showing:')
You.showHand(1)
print('The computer is showing:')
Computer.showHand(1)

# Here is where you decide to hit or stand.
while RepeatCardChoice == 0:
    CardChoice = str(input('Hit (H) or Stand (S)?'))
    if CardChoice == 'H':
        You.draw(deck, 1)
        HitCount += 1
        You.showHand(1+HitCount)
        RepeatCardChoice = 0  # This is so the player can keep deciding whether they still want to hit?
    elif CardChoice == 'S':
        RepeatCardChoice = 21  # Get it, because the winning score in blackjack is 21?
        HitCount = 0
    else:
        RepeatCardChoice = 0
    # Here is where we check your score.
    if YourScore > 21:
        exit('You busted and the computer wins!')
    elif YourScore == 21:
        exit('Blackjack, you win!')

# Here is where the computer hits or stands.
while ComputerScore <= 17:
    Computer.draw(deck, 1)
    HitCount +=1
    Computer.showHand(1+HitCount)
if ComputerScore>21:
    exit('The computer busted and you win!')
elif ComputerScore == 21:
    exit('Blackjack, the computer wins!')

# Here is where we compare the scores to decide the winner.
if ComputerScore > YourScore:
    exit('The computer wins!')
elif YourScore > ComputerScore:
    exit('You win!')
elif ComputerScore == YourScore:
    exit('You tied')
```

The output shouldn't provide any errors if the scoring system is successful, and I setup some variables that I might use to assign the score, however this can be changed as needed. Here is the output anyways.

```py
What is your name?Sample
You are showing:
KC
The computer is showing:
JS
Hit (H) or Stand (S)?H
KC
8S
Hit (H) or Stand (S)?S
JS
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Censored", line 119, in <module>
    Computer.draw(deck, 1)
  File "Censored", line 66, in draw
    self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
  File "Censored", line 54, in drawCard
    return self.cards.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Essentially, what is happening is that the computer hits infinitely due to a lack of scoring, until there is nothing left to draw, this is after you stand. I skipped a lot of lines in the output, as they're just a bunch of cards getting drawn.

Comment: I don't know blackjack, but looks to me you should add score-keeping the moment either player does a `showHand`? So each can decide what to do next. Win/lose is probably to be added in the `main` cycle, as a supervisor watching the game. Couple of notes however: there's an error at `value == 11` which I believe should be an assignment `value = 11`. Also, check your coding style: not to be picky, it really helps to follow conventions. CamelCase should be for class names, variables should all be lowercase, maybe with_underscores. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: In that same `if` statement inside class `Deck`, method `Cards`, this statement `if rank == (11) or (12) or (13):` doesn't do what you think it does; and also, you are checking twice for `rank == 1` which will not work. All in all, it needs some cleanup.